# storing physical labels from webform into a list C#

Tags: c#, list, label

I have searched for a while but can never get a clear answer on the correct way of doing this, or even if it is possible.
I am grabbing 2 rows from a table in SQL, returning them in a DataTable. I iterate through the rows and dynamically create a div for that row and then a label for each column with the stored value, and then repeats the process for the next row.

All I am missing to make it work is storing the labels into a List to bring back to the placeholder that the div will be created in.

here is a snippet... also, I want to do it this way, not with a gridview or tables for learning purposes and I already know how to use the gridview and table to do this. I have a total of 7 columns in this SQL table, and could have an unlimited number of rows.

*EDIT*

```
 public void AddDiv(DataTable gameData)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameData.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            //newControl.InnerHtml = AddLabel(gameData, i);
            //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(newControl);
            HtmlGenericControl newControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            newControl.ID = "div" + i++;

            Label lblTitle = new Label();
            lblTitle.Text = gameData.Rows[i]["Game_Title"].ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(lblTitle);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblTitle);

            Label lblPublisher = new Label();
            lblPublisher.Text = gameData.Rows[i]["Game_Publisher"].ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(lblPublisher);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblPublisher);

            Label lblGenre = new Label();
            lblGenre.Text = gameData.Rows[i]["Game_Genre"].ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(lblGenre);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblGenre);

            Label lblESRB = new Label();
            lblESRB.Text = gameData.Rows[i]["Game_ESRB"].ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(lblESRB);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblESRB);

            Label lblUserRating = new Label();
            lblUserRating.Text = gameData.Rows[i]["Game_UserRating"].ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(lblUserRating);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblUserRating);

            Label lblWebsite = new Label();
            lblWebsite.Text = gameData.Rows[i]["Game_Website"].ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(lblWebsite);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblWebsite);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, the InnerHtml property of the HtmlGenericControl is a string. Your code is assigning the result of a void method to this property. I think what you want to do is create the div and pass a reference to that to the AddLabel method. Here you can create your labels and add them to the div's Control's property. Finally, add your div to the Placeholder as you currently do. Hopefully, this will get you on the right track.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddDiv();
        }

        public void AddDiv()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl newControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                newControl.ID = "div" + i;
                AddLabel(newControl, i);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(newControl);
            }

        }

        protected void AddLabel(HtmlGenericControl control, int i)
        {
            Label lblTitle = new Label();
            lblTitle.Text = "label" + i.ToString();
            control.Controls.Add(lblTitle);

            Label lblPublisher = new Label();
            lblPublisher.Text = "publisherLabel" + i.ToString();
            control.Controls.Add(lblPublisher);
        }
```

Comment: That worked really well, thank you. the only thing now is that it's not creating a new div for each new row coming in.

Comment: So, it exits the loop and the creation of one div? What is the value of the count property? Also, rather than pass the table and the int i, I would pass the DataRow into the AddLabel method.

Comment: no, it goes through the loop the correct number of times, but only creates one div, won't create a second one, or third and so on... I changed it a bit so it is in one method. I'll edit the top so you can see...

Comment: In your methods, "this" refers to the page. So, you're adding the controls to the page and then the Placeholder. See my edited answer for an example.